# Como leer formato de hora de widget DateTimePicker para guardarlo en BD

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, reactjs

estoy usando DateTimePicker en React para hora y fecha, ese widget me da este formato:
Thu Aug 27 2020 17:57:09 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Perú), como haria para poder guardarlo en base de datos, el backend que estoy usando esta hecho en Laravel.
Estaba intentando con esto:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$request['datetime']);
```

Pero me da este error: Trailing data

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione agregando:

```
data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
```

al widget DateTimePicker

y en el backend reste 5 horas usando Carbon.